# Reasons to use getBy* in conjunction with toBeInTheDocument

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, jest-dom

There are plenty of examples of `getBy*` or `findBy*` queries are used in conjunction with `expect().toBeInTheDocument()`. At the same time [the Testing Library docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#types-of-queries) say that both of those type of queries throw errors when 0 elements match.

So there is a situation that when we do `expect(screen.getByText('some text')).toBeInTheDocument()` we're checking the element presence twice, which is redundant.

What's the reason everyone's doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's purely for readability. You don't really *need* the assertion `.toBeInTheDocument()`, or any other. As you say, in the failing case the error that fails the test is actually thrown by the `getBy*` method - `expect` is never even called.

However, using the `expect(actual).matcher(expected)` form makes it clearer that you're asserting on the presence of the element, whereas having `getBy*` on its own isn't very explicit. Readers will expect a test to have a certain "ryhthm", where some preconditions are set up (Arrange or Given), some action is taken (Act or When), and some postconditions are checked (Assert or Then). If a test ends *without* any `expect`ations, that can look like a mistake.

You may also have lint rules (like [`jest/expect-expect`](https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest/blob/main/docs/rules/expect-expect.md), although that can be configured to include `getBy*` as expectations) or Jest's own [`expect.hasAssertions()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expecthasassertions) that will be unhappy if you leave the assertion to be implicit, even in the passing case.

Testing Library has its own ESLint rules, which includes [`testing-library/prefer-explicit-assert`](https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library/blob/main/docs/rules/prefer-explicit-assert.md) covering this behaviour too; that says (emphasis mine):

> This rule aims to encourage users to explicitly assert existence of
> elements in their tests rather than just use `getBy*` queries and expect
> it doesn't throw an error **so it's easier to understand what's the
> expected behavior within the test**.